# Can windows Azure service bus queues can be accessed randomly

Tags: windows, azure, queue, cloud

Q1: Rather than traditional way of accessing queues, is it possible to access an element stored at nth position in azure service bus queues,

Q2: If answer to 1st is "Yes", then is it possible to update an element stored at nth position in azure service bus queue.

Usecase: I am using azure service bus queue to interact with different role instance running on azure, and to tell them to do this based on message recieved. Now in my scenario, it sometime happens that wrong ID is inserted in the queue (I cant help, that has to happen). So I was hoping if I am able to update the wrong ID at the side of role [the time when role recieved the queue]

Answer (score 1):

The Service Bus Queue is a queue. You can only modify content by enqueueing new messages. If you need an editable, time-ordered list, you should consider using a DB table.

With the new Peek() set of functions you can, however, enumerate messages without locking or deleting them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj908787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ONe thing we do is to update the property upon Abandon'ing the message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn130260.aspx

This may be one way for you to update the property if the id is wrong.